# How do I solve a bounded ODE with Maple?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

My task is to solve the ordinary differential equation $x^2y'' + 4xy' + (2+x^2)y = x^2$ with initial conditions $y(2\pi)=1$ and $y'(2\pi)=0$ on the interval $[0.5, 40]$. When I enter this into Maple with dsolve, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Maple 2015. This is my Maple equation:

```
dsolve({x^2*(diff(y(x), x, x))+4*(diff(xy(x), x))+(x^2+2)*y(x) = x^2, y(2*Pi) = 1, (D(y))(2*Pi) = 0})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

Just replace the term `4*diff(xy(x), x)` 
by `4*x*diff(y(x), x)`.